# Drupal AWS EC2 Instance Error - Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal

I followed the AWS guide on how to set up Drupal on AWS, everything installed fine and the command line is working well.

It's the basic site and set up with nothing custom.

I can access the site fine following the guide but when I try to log in I get the below error:

> To log in to this site, your browser must accept cookies from the domain ec2-XXX

[image]

After Googling, it mentions a patch could fix it but I can't seem to get it working.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to Open on Safari - I was already logged into the site!!

Must be an actual Chrome cookie issue, clean up those crumbs people!

Leaving in case someone needs the help....